# Tryinf to find a plane passing through a given point and parallel to two given lines

Tags: geometry

Suppose we are given a point $P$ on space and call lines $l$ and $m$ given. (Do we have to assume that these lines are parallel?)

If we pick a point in each line, say $Q$ and $S$, respectively in lines $l$ and $m$, then we can find a plane trough this 3 points, say place $PQS$. I am trying to visualize this, but it doesnt make sense. I feel like given lines $l$ and $m$ should be parallel. any help would be appreaciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always find a plane passing through one, two, or three points in three dimensional space.

Contrary to that, you can pick four or more points in the space such that there is no plane passing through all of them.

There are three points defined in the problem: $P$, $Q$ and $S$. Therefore there is always a plane containing all those three points. Whichever additional lines that are defined or not is irrelevant to the question whether you can find a plane containing those three points.

Comment: but the plane through these three points wont be parallel to the lines

Comment: Ah, well, sure. It was a little hard to understand. Yes, the lines should either be parallel, or intersect, or coincide for such a plane to exist.

Comment: can I assume that through given point $P$, there is a line passing through it?

Comment: Sure, why not?$               $

Comment: Because I thought we need two points at least to get a line...

Comment: It is true that to uniquely identify **one** line, you need two distinct points. However, nothing prevents you from picking *some* line passing through one point. It's just there is infinitely many of them.

Comment: I think I solved the problem: Suppose lines $l$ and $m$ are parallel and let $P$ be a given point. Pick two points in line $l$ and one point in line $m$. then through these three points, we can find a plane. Therefore, by using the corollary("through each point not lying on a given plane, there exists a unique plane parallel to the given one") in the book, we can find a plane passing through $P$ that is parallel to these lines. Is this correct argument?

Comment: Yeah, but you do not necessarily need the lines to be parallel. A pair of intersecting lines also uniquely identifies a plane.